# How to convert Delphi TPageControl "tab index" to "page index"?

Tags: delphi, tpagecontrol

I'm using a TPageControl, where certain pages are not visible.

This breaks the normal 1:1 mapping of the TabIndex and ActivePageIndex properties.

In most places I can use ActivePageIndex (or ActivePage itself) to get the current page, but I want a dynamic tooltip hint which requires me to determine which page is associated with a specific tab index.

If I call pageControl.IndexOfTabAt(X, Y), I get a Tab Index back, but I can't directly use that as an index into the Pages[] array, as some page tabs aren't visible.

I could explicity iterate through the pages, ignoring the visible ones, but it feels like there should be something in the VCL that does this for me already...?

Comment: Why do you need "to determine which page is associated with a specific tab index"?

Comment: @Leonardo: I'm dynamically creating pages and each page has a bunch of data members. Each tab has a dynamically generated "hint" extracted from the data, set by the PageControl onMouseMove(X,Y) which then calls IndexOfTabAt(X,Y) to determine which tab the mouse is over. Enough?

Answer (score 2):

I you look in the source for TPageControl (ComCtrls.pas), there is a private method:

```
function TPageControl.PageIndexFromTabIndex(TabIndex: Integer): Integer;
```

that does what you want.
But you can't call it (D2007), so (unfortunately) you have to copy the code.

Comment: Not only can you not call it, it doesn't even work right in many cases! http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=30263

Answer (score 0):

This version seems to work:

```
function PageIndexFromTabIndex(const pageControl : TPageControl; const TabIndex: Integer): Integer;
 var
    i : Integer;
 begin
   Result := TabIndex;
   for i := 0 to Pred(pageControl.PageCount) do
     begin
       if not pageControl.Pages[i].TabVisible then
         Inc(Result);
       if TabIndex = pageControl.Pages[i].TabIndex then
         break;
     end;
  end;
```

Answer (score -1):

[Here is an old article](http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2004/a/bltip0304_3.htm) that deals with dragging & dropping pages. It has some logic to obtain the index of a page from an (X, Y) position, perhaps you can use it. Something like this (untested):

```
function TMyPageControl.GetPageIndexAtPos(X, Y: Integer) : Integer;
const
   TCM_GETITEMRECT = $130A;
var
   TabRect: TRect;
   j: Integer;    
begin
   for j := 0 to PageCount - 1 do
   begin
     Perform(TCM_GETITEMRECT, j, LParam(@TabRect)) ;
     if PtInRect(TabRect, Point(X, Y)) then
     begin
       Result := j;
       exit;
     end;
   end;
   Result := -1;
end;
```